# Apache Kafka 1.0.0 Streams API Multiple Multilevel groupby

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

How do i use .groupby with Multiple constrainst in Kafka Streams API. Same as in Java 8 Streams API example below

```
public void twoLevelGrouping(List<Person> persons) {
     final Map<String, Map<String, List<Person>>> personsByCountryAndCity = persons.stream().collect(
         groupingBy(Person::getCountry,
            groupingBy(Person::getCity)
        )
    );
    System.out.println("Persons living in London: " + personsByCountryAndCity.get("UK").get("London").size());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You specify a combined key by putting all attributes/fields you want to group-by into the key.

```java
KTable table = stream.selectKey((k, v,) -> k::getCountry + "-" + k::getCity)
                     .groupByKey()
                     .aggregate(...); // or maybe .reduce()
```

I just assumed that country and city are both `String`. You use Interactive Queries to query the store with

```java
store.get("UK-London");
```

https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html

Comment: I do not think this is the right way, But, I agree that it does the job. Is there any better way to do so??

Comment: The answer is a sketch. It would be better to introduce some POJO type that contains two fields, one for the country, one for the city (or in general one field per grouping attribute) and emit this new type in `selectKey()` -- you will also need to write custom Serdes for the type that you need to set in `groupByKey` and `aggregate()`. The aggregate function will get the this POJO as input type to do the aggregation. Of course, a POJO is just one way to do this, you can also use a Tuple type or any other combined type.

Comment: I have already used a custom POJO, and custom serde with GSON.  Could you please explain me more.

Comment: Not sure what I should explain more... Instead of putting two attributes into a single String, emit the POJO that wraps both attributes. This will automatically group by both attributes.

Comment: sorry for being a noob, i really can use a example please!

Comment: also am a big fan of ksql. looking forward for first stable release today/7th